# Convert PCIe x1 slot to open ended. Is there a safe way to cut the closed edge?

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, pcie, virtual-machines, manufacturing

Unfortunately, most manufacturers currently produce only motherboards with close end at their pcie x1 slots. There are many reasons why people want to have free end slots. And I am surprised why close end slots are still placed.

I have a usual motherboard, and I have an extension card (a usb controller) that is x4 size. My motherboard has three pcie x16 size slots, but I cannot use one of them for usb controller pcie x4 card: the pcie16_1 is for GPU, the pcie16_2 is free, but has improper iommu isolation (it is grouped with pciex16_1 slot), and pcie16_3 is for second GPU.

I want to mount my usb controller to one of the pcie x1 slots. It fits there, and so I do not need to use riser. The only problem is the close end of the slot.

I wish to convert the pcie x1 slots to free edge. Are there reliable safe ways to do it? I do not want to risk damaging my motherboard. Does some tools exist for this task (probably pcie edge cutters/scissors)?

Answer (score 3):

I would follow this method with a couple of additional precautions. See the video, she is using a small pointed grinding bit to slowly remove the plastic. Start on the outside and work from bottom up. I recommend placing some cardboard onto the MB directly below the grinding position and also put something into the slot to prevent grinding too deep and also to keep debris out. Several x1 USB cards (see pic) are just a few bucks to protect the slot while you work.

[image]
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxUwTP98Z3U

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways I found safe is to just replace slot sockets with proper one.

I have found the following item on AliExpress, called PCIe slot 36p socket 1x graphics card slot black one side open straight in

[image]

Buy sockets, then bring the motherboard to local repairs center and ask them to replace them (unsolder closed end slots, then solder open side slots).